# Delete rows with missing values from certain location in data frame python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Good people, still learning python.Now I have a very huge dataframe of around 1 million rows however I do what to delete rows which have missing values  from certain column location. I mean after locating rows with missing values from certain column, I should be able to delete the entire row.Look at the sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 

data = {'A':['NW', 'NB', 'UK', 'CAN'],'B':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'C':[20, '', 19, ''],'D':[20, '', 19, ''],'E':[20, '', 19, ''],'F':[20, '', 19, '']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
print(df)
```

in this dataframe, I want to identify rows with missing values from  *column C to column F* then delete entire row, which means I have to delete *row 1 and row 3*. I have tried this but it aint working :

```
df.dropna(subset=['C','D','E','F'], how='all', inplace = True)
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT should be a table like this

```
import pandas as pd 

data = {'A':['NW', 'UK'],'B':['Tom', 'krish'], 'C':[20, 19],'D':[20, 19 ],'E':[20,  19 ],'F':[20, 19]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
print(df)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [`pandas.DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html)

- Use `mask` to make the dataframe null anywhere a condition is `True`
- Then use `dropna` with the `subset` argument

This is instead of using `replace` as mentioned by zipa and jezrael.  There isn't any advantage to using this over the other methods.  I just like using `mask`.  It also serves the community to show another method for accomplishing the task.

---

```
df.mask(df.eq('')).dropna(subset=['C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])

    A      B   C   D   E   F
0  NW    Tom  20  20  20  20
2  UK  krish  19  19  19  19
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True).dropna()
```

Comment: Solution remove all rows with any '', so it is wrong, need `df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True).dropna(subset=['C','D','E','F'], how='all')`

Answer (score 2):

One solution is compare empty strings in list of columns and get at least one one `''` per rows:

```
df = df[df[['C','D','E','F']].ne('').any(1)]
```

**Details**:

```
print(df[['C','D','E','F']].ne(''))
       C      D      E      F
0   True   True   True   True
1  False  False  False  False
2   True   True   True   True
3  False  False  False  False

print (df[['C','D','E','F']].ne('').any(1))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Alternative with inverted condition by `~`:

```
df = df[~df[['C','D','E','F']].eq('').all(1)]
```

**Details**:

```
print(df[['C','D','E','F']].eq(''))
       C      D      E      F
0  False  False  False  False
1   True   True   True   True
2  False  False  False  False
3   True   True   True   True

print (df[['C','D','E','F']].eq('').all(1))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool

print (~df[['C','D','E','F']].eq('').all(1))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

---

```
print(df)
    A      B   C   D   E   F
0  NW    Tom  20  20  20  20
2  UK  krish  19  19  19  19
```

For working with your solution is necessary replace empty strings to missing values first:

```
df = df.replace('',np.nan)
df.dropna(subset=['C','D','E','F'], how='all', inplace = True)
print(df)
    A      B     C     D     E     F
0  NW    Tom  20.0  20.0  20.0  20.0
2  UK  krish  19.0  19.0  19.0  19.0
```